# Android Loopj image upload broken with WP API v1 & v2

Tags: android, wordpress, loopj, wp-api

I'm using Loopj to upload files into my WordPress site and WP REST API v1 and/or v2 (same results).

The authentications goes great, headers goes great, file "uploads" but when I check it in my WordPress backend... the image or file is broken.

The Android part goes like this:

```
File myFile = new File(finalpath);

String name = Utils.getLastBitFromUrl(finalpath);

String extension = Utils.getFileExtention(finalpath);

client.setBasicAuth("myusername", "mypassword", new AuthScope("mywebsite.com", 80, AuthScope.ANY_REALM));

     client.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + name);
     client.addHeader("Content-Type", "image/" + extension);

     try {
        params.put("data", myFile);
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
     }
     // or: http://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media for v2
     client.post("http://mywebsite.com/wp-json/media", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

          int count = 0;

          @Override
          public void onStart() {
            prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            prgDialog.setMessage("Uploading Image...");
            prgDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            prgDialog.setMax(100);
            prgDialog.show();
          }

          @Override
          public void onProgress(long bytesWritten, long totalSize) {

              if(count < 1){
                 count++;
                 Log.d("size", "" + Utils.formatFileSize(totalSize));
              }

          long progressPercentage = (long)100*bytesWritten/totalSize;

          if(progressPercentage <= 100) {
              prgDialog.setProgress((int) progressPercentage);
            }
          }

          @Override
          public void onSuccess(int statuscode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
             try {
               prgDialog.dismiss();
               JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(Utils.decodeUTF8(response));

               Log.e("success!", Utils.decodeUTF8(response));

             } catch (JSONException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
```

But the image... looks like this in my WordPress backend:

[image: Image Broken]

Does anyone have any idea why this happen? My file and File Path are perfect. I can get the image and show it on my phone before upload it.

EDIT: This cURL works perfect

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Disposition:filename=test.png" --data-binary @"/home/my-name/Downloads/example.png" -d title="test" -u username:password -H "Expect:" http://my.website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media
```

The main difference is over --data-binary @ but I don't know how to do that over Java.

Comment: hi i m facing the same problem here.... have you solved this?

Comment: Not yet :( I'm following the github project to see if anyone solve this.

Comment: hey if you solve the problem please post the solution.... :)

Comment: Please check whether the file is loadable and broken from the browser, could be that image is not attached properly.
Also try another image with different format - I've had a similar issue, when I had to re save images in photoshop to stop wordpress thinking the image is broken e.g. if image been converted to different format in a wrong way.

Comment: Someone got this working?

Answer (score 1):

I think your image not attached properly . Please check with postman check my screenshot below [image]
[image]

Comment: Yes but than, what would be the proper way to attach. I've tried sending it as a URI, File, byte[], .. It keeps being broken. My guess it should be byte[].